# What does it mean when an AFCI breaker indicator is 1/4 white?

Tags: electrical

My renters are complaing that the breaker for the master bather and bedroom keeps tripping.  They say the trip is random.  I tested all the plugs and GFCI plug in the bathroom.  Everything passed with my GFCI tester.  The house had a unwelcome rat for a few weeks and could have chewed a wire, really hope not.

The only odd thing I can see is the breaker shows 1/4 white on the arch fault indicator.

Could that be the issue?[image: breaker]

Comment: Are you certain that's a GFCI breaker. It'd have to be a dual because the one @ the bottom in the pic is an AFCI (Arc Fault Circuit Interrupter).

Comment: Always learning.  I think the issue is the surge protector they have.